# Using assert statements only through Microsoft Nutter to unit test raised exception in Databricks notebooks

Tags: python, unit-testing, databricks

I am using the MS Nutter framework to unit test python functions written in Databricks notebooks, https://github.com/microsoft/nutter.

One function raises a `ValueError` exception. How do I test for this correctly via Nutter?

Nutter only seems to include `assert` commands, nothing like `with pytest.raises(ValueError)`. Is there a workaround to use `assert` to test exceptions? Or is there part of Nutter that I have not discovered that allows for this?

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating Fabrice answer (Hope it helps):

```
def assertion_valuerrorcheck():
   try:
      valueErrorFlag = False
      try:
         #code which raises value error
      except ValueError:
         valueErrorFlag = True
      assert(valueErrorFlag) #if True, case is passed
   except AssertionError:
         #print why assertion failed
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use exception-handling in the run-function to set a flag and use the assertion to identify if the flag is set.

Comment: Thanks for this Fabrice. What would this look like in code?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).